# Why separated template constexpr / inline function implementation from declaration works fine with explicit instantiation?

Tags: c++, function, templates

I'm wondering why this example works just fine as implementation for a template `constexpr`, `inline` or even `consteval` function should be visible by the compiler!

I expected that linker throws errors about using both operator+ and dot functions!

```
//--------------------vector3.h-------------------------

#ifndef VECTOR3_H
#define VECTOR3_H

template <typename T> class Vector3
{
public:
    explicit Vector3<T>() = default;
    constexpr explicit Vector3<T>(T, T, T);
    template <typename U> friend constexpr U dot(const Vector3<U>&, const Vector3<U>&);
    inline Vector3<T> operator+(Vector3<T>&);
private:
    T array[3];
};

#endif // VECTOR3_H

//--------------------vector3.cpp-------------------------

#include "vector3.h"

template <typename U>
constexpr U dot(const Vector3<U>& vec1, const Vector3<U>& vec2)
{
    return vec1.array[0] * vec2.array[0] +
           vec1.array[1] * vec2.array[1] +
           vec1.array[2] * vec2.array[2];
}
template<typename T>
constexpr Vector3<T>::Vector3(T x, T y, T z):
    array{x, y, z}
{

}

template<typename T>
Vector3<T> Vector3<T>::operator+(Vector3<T>& vec)
{
    return Vector3{array[0] + vec.array[0], array[1] + vec.array[1], array[2] + vec.array[2]};
}


template class Vector3<double>;
template class Vector3<float>;

template double dot<double>(const Vector3<double>&, const Vector3<double>&);

//--------------------main.cpp-------------------------

#include <iostream>
#include "vector3.h"

int main()
{
    Vector3<double> i{5.4, 32.3, -3.2};
    Vector3<double> j{1, 0, -1};
    double result {dot(i + j, j)};
    std::cout << "Result is: " << result << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't use them in `constexpr` context.

Comment: `inline` is just for ODR, unrelated to inlining, so definition is not required to be visible.

Comment: I don't see `consteval` usage.

Comment: Isn't `constexpr U dot(const Vector3<U>& vec1, const Vector3<U>& vec2)` Ill-formed; No diagnostic required since it can never be called in a constant expression (at least pre C++20)?

Comment: You have explicit instatiations in the `cpp` file. They are found when linking, so there's no issue.

Comment: Dear @Jarod42 if you separate a ```constexpr``` or ```inline``` function from its implementation you will get linker error!

Comment: Dear @NathanOliver this is my another question whether dot function can be evaluated at compile time or not due to separated implementation/ declaration!

Comment: I don't see why you would got linker error for inline function. `inline` is just to allow to have several identical definition.

Comment: Dear @super thank you! Doesn't you expect a linker error since implementation and usage of functions are in two different translation units?

Comment: @NimaGhorab No. I would expect a linker error if there is no implementation to be found in any translation unit. But you have an implementation that's been explicitly instatiated from your template in `vector3.cpp`.

Comment: Dear @Jarod42 If you separate implementation of an inline function from its declaration you will get linker error!

Comment: So dear @super why linker can't find implementation for an ordinary constexpr or inline function if its implementation and declaration are in .cpp/.h files respectively?

Comment: @Jarod42: [basic.def.odr]/11 requires that any inline function odr-used in a translation unit be defined there.  In practice the compiler might reject this or it might merely fail to emit code for the inline function (if no translation unit that defines it takes its address or fails to inline a call to it), provoking a linker error.

Comment: @NathanOliver: It’s only the body of a constexpr function that’s subject to the “must be callable” rule—a non-defining declaration is simply unusable in constant expressions and requires a definition if odr-used (because it’s inline).